# PushKit PKPushRegistryDelegate does not get callbacks

Tags: ios, swift

After upgrading my app to Xcode8/Swift 3, I no longer receive callbacks from the `PKPushRegistryDelegate`.

I have verified all steps in [Apple´s Voice Over IP (VoIP) Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html).

My device logs the following that might be related:

> callservicesd[92] : [WARN] Ignoring voipRegister request because either no bundleIdentifier could be determined (0) or no environment could be determined (1)

My AppDelegate:

```
var voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
  voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)    
  voipRegistry.delegate = self    
  voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([.voIP])    
}

extension AppDelegate: PKPushRegistryDelegate {    
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenForType type: PKPushType) {        
        print("didInvalidatePushTokenForType")        
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {        
        print("Incoming voip notfication: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, forType type: PKPushType) {               
        print("voip token: \(credentials.token)")        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured I had to enable "Push Notifications" under my target´s Capabilities:

[image]